# Convert string to timestamp and use timestamp_diff in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have two different strings:

created = `2019-06-30T17:33:09.879350220Z`
updated = `2019-09-25 06:42:45`

I have to perform `TIMESTAMP_DIFF(created_date, updated_date, HOUR)` in a condition.

For the second one, `CAST(updated AS TIMESTAMP)` works but when I do `CAST(created AS TIMESTAMP)`, it shows me an error `Invalid Timestamp`.

How can I cast the created string to a `TIMESTAMP` most efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this format is kinda tricky but works with a [format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-timestamp) like this:

```
select parse_timestamp('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ','2019-06-30T17:33:09.879350220Z')
```

returns:

```
2019-06-30 17:33:09.879350 UTC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parse_timestamp()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_timestamp).

```sql
  SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2019-09-25 06:42:45')
```